# Microsoft Azure OAuth 2.0 - Can you store Authorization tokens for reuse?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have an app that currently uses basic auth to read an Exchange Online mailbox. We are looking at upgrading our basic auth to OAuth2.0 since basic auth is being depricated. This app runs as a service, and reads and replies to messages in the mailbox.

Since the app reads an account's mailbox, the [Daemon app scenario doesn't apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview), since it needs to log in as a user. For now we have this working using a [username and password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), and by providing user consent for the mailbox user by logging in and consenting via the oauth2 authorization link in a browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.send%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.readwrite
```

This gives consent for the app to log into the user's mailbox and read/send emails via a username password. However, this scenario is not ideal and not recommended by Microsoft.

What I need is a way for an app to read a mailbox as a user without the need of multiple interactive prompts - i.e. we authorize the app and provide consent once to log in and use a mailbox, and then after that we can store that authorization, and re-use that authorization to log-in next time. Essentially, I need to have the authorization stored permanently after an initial authorization.

The [Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) seems to do this - the auth token is requested using an interactive login, then requests an access token using that auth token. If that access token expires, the auth token can be used to request a new access token. Our auth token could be kept and re-used without a new interactive prompt.

So my question is, after authorizing and giving consent for a user and receiving an authorization token (via a web app, or a console app, or even with the url above), can that token be stored and reused? My current code gets an access token by username/password each time:

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
var accounts = await App.GetAccountsAsync();

if (accounts.Any())
{
    result = await (App as Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication).AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
        .ExecuteAsync();
}
else
{
    try
    {
        result = await App.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, password)
        .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch () //Handle different exception here
    {
    }
}

return result;
```

And then uses the AccessToken from that AuthenticationResult to instantiate a new GraphServiceClient

```
    string sToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage
            .Headers
            .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", sToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
```

If I do a one-time authorization and store that token, can I re-use that token for logins later (use it to get a new access token)? I was under the impression that these tokens are not long-term. What's the lifecycle of the auth tokens, can they be used this way? And if they can, how do I replace my App.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword request to request an Access Token by passing in an Auth token instead of a username/password?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you might not be doing token caching properly. After authentication your app receives a refresh token that can be used to get a new access token. Check the docs on caching e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens

Comment: @juunas Once logged in with a username/password I can successfully cache the token. That works OK, however I don't want to have that requirement to log in with the username and password if possible.

Once logged in I can get a new access token using App.AcquireTokenSilent, but that's only after logging in with username/password in the service. Is there any way of getting the auth token interactively outside of the service (it's a windows service with no interface), and then storing that auth token somewhere where the service can access it?

Comment: Certainly. We have done this in a Web app, the fundamental approach should be the same. What you need to do is use the same token cache from both places, for example a file that both processes can access. You would most likely have to take some steps to protect this file from unwanted access, but I'm not the most knowledgeable person for desktop stuff :/ The samples do have token cache implementations for desktop apps that use files.

Comment: You can achieve this. Check out the code sample here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnet-advanced-token-cache